# How to save autocomplete information (locally) for a form without redirecting/refresing the page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, autocomplete, form-submit

I have a form I'm submitting via ajax with jQuery, it's part of a system that'll replace an 
existing one, there's a functionality problem I'm facing thouhg. On the current system, users fill out all the form's information and submits, normally thought the form's submit button, I've noticed in those cases the autocomplete information for form elements with the same name will be saved locally on the browser (in this case most users will use Google Chrome), however, when trying to submit the form's data through ajax, nothing will be saved. The users will be sometimes imputing repetitive information (but not to the point were it'd be a good idea to have a list on the server to use jQuery autocomplete). My code when clicking the submit button (instead of submitting the normal way) is currently something like this:

```
jQuery("<submit button>").click(function() {
    <form validation and other stuff>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<some perl script>',
        data: '<form data>',
        success: function(data) {
            if(<expected response from server>){
                if(<certain input on the form has a specific value>){
                    <do something>
                }
            } else {
                <do something else>
            }
    });
})
```

This is my first question here, and I looked all over trying to find a solution before deciding to post it, if you think I'm not making enough sense, I'll try to include more data.

Basically what I want is to be able to save the information for every form field for future use on with the browser's autocomplete, but I haven't been able to pull it off using ajax. I think there's something that only works for Internet Explorer called window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm but I'm not sure (anyways this whole system won't be used with explorer).

NOTE: What I want is to save previous entered values on the autocomplete/suggestions or whatever you want to call it, so let's say a user submits the value "Something" for input "name", I want the users to be able to write the letter "S" and the browser's autocomplete to show a list of previously entered values (not displaying anything specific by default) including the "Something" that was entered on a previous submit (and other matching ones like "Something else", "Something Wrong", etc). For what I've tested so far, "submitting" the form with ajax (and returning false to avoid the page to reload) won't save the previous submitted info for future autocomplete use (at least on in Chrome, which is the browser that concerns me).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the question: Is it that you want to submit the form via AJAX and it's actually submitting the entire form, thus directing the page to the `<form action="{url}">` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm doing something like <form action="javascript:void(0)"> and actually submitting the form purely with ajax

Comment: The question is very unclear, you don't actually mention what it is. :-/

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, i didn't find out what you want to do finally.

Comment: Please specify that you want to save entered values or returned suggestions ?

Comment: @darkajax as you're new to stackoverflow, here are a few tips that would help: When asking questions, try to be as clear and concise as possible. The trick to getting a good answer, is asking a good question the right way. It's not about supplying as much detail as you can, but making the question as simple and clear as possible. So for example, I would have asked: "Browser does not save form data on AJAX form submit, how can I use an AJAX form and have the browser save the form data on submit?" It's a single line question. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't actually mention the question. I am going out on a limb here, but you want the browser to save the form data when the user submits it. I am guessing these are some sort of form queries.

I think most modern browsers support auto complete when an XHR is made, I maybe wrong.
In any case, you could submit the data via an iframe and trick the browser into beleiving that the page has changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hijack the form submit, it's better to do so using [jQuery.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) rather than "click".
To prevent the form from actually submitting (since your AJAX is going to do it instead), you should use `return false`

Example:

```
jQuery('#form').submit(function() {
    // <form validation and other stuff>
    var $form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<some perl script>',
        data: $form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            if(<expected response from server>){
                if(<certain input on the form has a specific value>){
                    <do something>
                }
            } else {
                <do something else>
            }
    });

    return false;
})
```

Comment: That's a good idea, however the problem remains, by submitting the form this way the information is not saved on the browser's autocomplete for future use...

Comment: Have you tried it? -- Each browser is going to be different in the way this is handled. Some will save the form data, and others won't. The only way that I'm aware is to trick the browser into believing it has submitted a real form by using an iframe (even hidden) with the form data in it. But this is a bad thing to do, it goes against the rules of Mankind. But you really should test this and see if the browser will save the form data. (Make sure it's on in your browser)

Comment: Yes I tried it, it didn't work on Chrome (which is the one I need it to work on) if I stop the reload with "return false;"

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Aye Carumba, this is not at all clear!

Ok, if you're truly submitting via ajax, the form shouldn't actually disappear, hence no need to save anything.  Without the form code it's impossible to see what's exactly going on.  However, if you have a button or form submit element inside of `<form>` tags, the form is doing what HTML's default is....submitting the form to the form action.  That would cause the form to clear, and likely would be bypassing your ajax action altogether.

Throw an event.preventDefault in your click function.  See what happens.....

```
jQuery("<submit button>").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
<form validation and other stuff>
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<some perl script>',
    data: '<form data>',
    success: function(data) {
        if(<expected response from server>){
            if(<certain input on the form has a specific value>){
                <do something>
            }
        } else {
            <do something else>
        }
});
```

})

That would override the form's default functionality, which would be to submit and clear the form.  Now, everything should stay put, with no clearing.  You could selectively clear elements or leave them all as you wish from there.

Please, please add more detail to your question!

Comment: I believe the question is actually the reverse: How to get the browser to save form data submitted via AJAX.

Comment: correct, I want the browser saving the form data for autocomplete/suggestions when the user wants to write the same thing again on the future.